# Azure private endpoint in Hub spoke

Tags: azure, azure-hub

I've implemented Hub-Spoke with azure firewall in hub.
We send all traffics to firewall and hub-spoke peering enabled with traffic forwarding and gateway transit is also enabled.
I have a postgres with private endpoint in one spoke and I want to connect from other spoke to the postgres which I get connection timeout.
I have tested the connection with a Vm running in other spoke which I can connect to it.

I can also connect directly from Hub to postgres.
The only issue is Spoke to Spoke communication for private endpoint doesn't work.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: hi Pers, Can you run a wireshark scan and check where the connection drops out?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue .It was from Firewall and I had to add a rule for those spokes.